# How can there be a zero sequence current in a single line to ground fault with an ungrounded neutral

Tags: high-voltage, transmission-line, short-circuit, power-engineering, fault

The circuit that describes a single line to ground fault in a system with an ungrounded neutral is:
[image]

I neglect capacitance between phases and only look at capacitance to ground.
The definition of zero sequence current is
$$I^{(0)} = \frac{1}{3}(I_1 + I_2 + I_3)$$
But if apllied to the circuit above, Kirchoff current law should state that:$$(I_1 + I_2 + I_3) = 0$$
So how can there be a zero sequence current in this circuit? What am I missing here?

Comment: If I take two actual capacitors and connect them between phases A-B and A-C will a zero sequence current flow in this circuit? Spice says that at each moment in time the sum of all phase currents will be 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parasitic phase-ground capacitance is a load in all three sequence networks. Even though your zero sequence source impedance is infinite (delta), the capacitance provides a path for sequence current to flow.  In the figure below i show the 3 sequence networks for your system.  The red lines show how they are interconnected for an A-phase to ground fault.  This should help.

[image]

If you calculate the B & C phase currents in the parasitic capacitance (from the sequence currents you calculate with the above circuit) you will see the phase current path clearer.

[image]

**UPDATE**:  Added further explanation on calculating the sequence components and phase currents in the fault, in the ph-ground capacitance, and from the transformer. Note the reference arrows i chose (if you use opposite direction just flip phase angle by 180):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109254/discussion-on-answer-by-relayman357-how-can-there-be-a-zero-sequence-current-in).